# Get top records for each group in sql

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which has 3 columns StudentID, Score and ClassNumber.
What I need now is to select top 5 students of each Class (according to their Score result).

For example if there are 20 students in Class1, 40 students in Class2 and students in Class3, I need to select 15 top score students for each Class(5 for Class1, 5 for Class2, 5 for Class3)

How can I do this in one SQL query?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: For which database and version ?  For Oracle and SqlServer you have the row_number window function that can group and enumerate records within the group.  Then you can query the top(x) from each.

Comment: @AmirPelled: window functions are not limited to Oracle and SQL Server. Every modern DBMS supports them. Even MySQL will arrive in the 21st century with the upcoming version 8.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean somthing like this?

```
with tmp as
(
    select ClassNumber,
           StudentID,
           Score,
           row_number() over (partition by ClassNumber order by Score desc) row_num, 
    from Student s
)

select ClassNumber, StudentID, Score
from tmp
where row_num <= 5
order by ClassNumber
```

Comment: Did you consider scenario where more than one student have same score?

Comment: Its select only 5 students for class, Test it. If there is any preference for this case - can add the relevant column to the order section within the row_number() function.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in MYSQL :

```
SELECT StudentID, Score, ClassNumber
   FROM
     (SELECT StudentID, Score, ClassNumber, 
                  @class_rank := IF(@current_class = classNumber, @class_rank + 1, 1) AS class_rank,
                  @current_class := ClassNumber
       FROM student
       ORDER BY ClassNumber, score DESC
     ) ranked
   WHERE class_rank <= 5;
```

Solution in SQL SERVER:

```
select ClassNumber, StudentID, Score
from (
select ClassNumber,
           StudentID,
           Score,
           dense_rank() over (partition by ClassNumber order by Score desc) ranking 
    from Student s
) as t
where ranking <= 5
order by ClassNumber
```

Comment: It's working perfectly this way. Thanks so much Nishant.

Comment: If you find it useful please accept the answer.@Julia